# Why do people say aviation regulations are written in blood?

Tags: regulations

I have heard it said that all aviation regulations are "written in blood". I think this means that every rule in the book exists because someone died - and there was a lesson learned. Is this accurate? Is there anything else to the story of this phrase?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, that's all it means. Aviation regulations tend to be put in place in response to accident reports, where a plane crashed or almost crashed for lack of the regulations. So, if you're confused why a stupid-seeming regulation exists, there's a good chance that people died because of the thing the regulation changed.

Obviously, not *all* regulations are like that; for instance, noise limits are based on quality of life for those near airports, not crashes. However, a good number of aviation rules came into effect as recommendations following a crash report.

Comment: Not all _safety-related_ regulations are like that either. Many are result of simply realizing something is safety-critical already during design and many are results of _incident_ reports which is when something went wrong without causing any injury or much damage, but increased risk of accident was recognized and gets addressed.