# Are there any countermeasures for lasers or the people who use them to blind pilots?

Tags: safety, laser-illumination

Yesterday there has been another laser-incident at my local airport LOWG. The laser hit the cockpit twice, but the pilot managed to land the Dash 8 Q400 safely.

I'm taking this recent event as opportunity to ask, if there are any countermeasures at the time, be it in use already or in development, against these despicable people or their lasers?

Comment: I can think of a few active countermeasures, but i'm afraid that those would lead to some serious human rights issues...

Comment: Is it possible to [blend pilots?](http://www.willitblend.com/)

Comment: See the answer here:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25464/does-the-faa-advise-or-require-pilots-to-wear-eyewear-designed-to-protect-them-f?rq=1

Comment: @abelenky Oh, thank you. In German "blenden" means "to blind", so I just used "blend". My mistake.